# SQLAlchemy: Define a model whose member names differ from the column names

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Consider the following table in a [PostgreSQL 9.3](http://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1481/) database:

```
                        Table "public.text"
   Column   |            Type             |       Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+------------------------
 name       | character varying(255)      | not null
 lang       | character varying(3)        | not null
 text       | character varying(255)      |
 time_stamp | timestamp without time zone | not null default now()
Indexes:
    "text_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (name, lang)
```

The table is modelled by the following Python class using [SQLALchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) [Base](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/declarative.html):

```
class Text(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'text'
    __table_args__ = (PrimaryKeyConstraint(name, lang),)

    name = Column(String(255))
    lang = Column(String(3))
    text = Column(String(255))
    time_stamp = Column(Date)

    def __init__(self, name, lang, text):
        self.name = name
        self.lang = lang
        self.text = text
    ...
```

The identifiers of the class members (`name`, `lang`, `text`, `time_stamp`) are identical to those of the DB table.

How do I define a class with different member identifiers, which will be mapped to existing table columns? For example, I would like to map `Text.langugage` to the table column `lang`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify the name of the column on the database as a first argument:

```
language = Column('lang', String(3))
```

Read [`Column(...)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.__init__) documentation for more information.